# How to get document when I select a document in IBM Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

When I select one or more documents in IBM Lotus Notes, how can I get it when I click a button above?
[image]

Example:how can I get data for row1 and row2 when i click button:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim session As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Set dc = db.AllDocuments
Set doc =??? document on row1 & row2
End Sub
```

Please help me solve this problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [UnprocessedDocuments property](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/fa9dc4724dab0fed8525642e007702d6?OpenDocument) which will return a collection that you can loop through.